# How do I set std::ios_base flags like std::left in boost log 2.0?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I have an application which makes extensive use of boost log 2.0. Now I would like to set some default flags for that application like `std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1)`, `std::scientific` and `std::left`. But how do I do that? One approach is creating a logger at the very beginning of my main function and creating a dummy log message. This permanently sets the desired flags. But is there no nicer way to do this?

**edit** in reply to: *"OP should show actual code."*

I have a global Logging singleton, called L:

```
class L{
public:
  enum severity_level
  {
      dddebug,
      ddebug,
      debug,
      control,
      iiinfo,
      iinfo,
      info,
      result,
      warning,
      error,
      critical
  };

  typedef boost::log::sources::severity_channel_logger<
      severity_level, // the type of the severity level
      std::string // the type of the channel name
  > logger_t;
  typedef boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink< boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend > text_sink;
  boost::shared_ptr< text_sink > sink_;

  static L& get();
  static boost::shared_ptr<text_sink> sink();
  static double t0();
  static double tElapsed();
private:
  L();
  double t0_p;
  static std::string tElapsedFormat();

  L(const L&) = delete;
  void operator=(const L&) = delete;
};
```

which provides a logging sink, severity levels and utilizes MPI methods for synchronized timekeeping across MPI nodes. THe implementation of the class members follows here:

```
#include "log.h"

#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/log/attributes/function.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/make_shared_object.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_channel_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>


namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

#include "mpiwrap.h"
#include <mpi.h>

BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(t, "Time", std::string)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(rank, "Rank", int)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(channel, "Channel", std::string)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(severity, "Severity", L::severity_level)

L::L():
  sink_(boost::make_shared< text_sink >()),
  t0_p(MPI_Wtime())
{

  sink_->locked_backend()->add_stream(
    boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >("log." + std::to_string(MpiWrap::getRank())));

  sink_->set_formatter
  (
    expr::stream
      << "< "
      << t << " "
      << "[p:" << rank << "] "
      << "[c:" << channel << "] "
      << "[s:" << severity << "] "
      << expr::smessage
  );

  logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink_);

  logging::core::get()->set_filter(

       (channel == "ChannelName1" && severity >= dddebug)
    || (channel == "ChannelName2" && severity >= info)
    || (channel == "ChannelName3" && severity >= result)

  );

  // Add attributes
  logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("Time", attrs::make_function(&tElapsedFormat));
  logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("Rank", attrs::constant<int>(MpiWrap::getRank()));
}

L& L::get(){
  static L instance;
  return instance;
}

boost::shared_ptr<L::text_sink> L::sink(){
  return get().sink_;
}

double L::t0(){
  return get().t0_p;
}

double L::tElapsed(){
  return MPI_Wtime() - t0();
}

std::string L::tElapsedFormat(){
  std::stringstream ss;
  const int prec = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10;
  ss << std::setw(prec + 2 + 6) << std::left << std::setprecision(prec) << tElapsed();
  return ss.str();
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& strm, L::severity_level level)
{
    static const char* strings[] =
    {
        "DBG3",
        "DBG2",
        "DBG1",
        "CTRL",
        "INF3",
        "INF2",
        "INF1",
        "RSLT",
        "WARN",
        "ERRR",
        "CRIT"
    };

    if (static_cast< std::size_t >(level) < sizeof(strings) / sizeof(*strings))
        strm << strings[level];
    else
        strm << static_cast< int >(level);

    return strm;
}
```

Now for the usage: My classes usually have a static `logger_t` (typedef for `boost::log::sources::severity_channel_logger<severity_level, std::string>`) member

```
class A {
public:
    logger_t logger;
    //other stuff here
    void function_which_does_logging();
};

L::logger_t A::logger(boost::log::keywords::channel = "ClassA");

void A::function_which_does_logging(){
    //do non logging related stuff
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, L::result) << "the error is: " << 0.1234567890;
    //do non logging related stuff
}
```

My current solution to the problem is putting a logging statement in the beginning of my program

```
int main(){
    L::logger_t logger(boost::log::keywords::channel = "init");
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, L::critical) << "setting up logger" << std::scientific << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1);

    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Formatting is very seldom needed for logging. If formatting is needed, then you could use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) for the formatting, and just log the pre-formatted string.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg for my work it is essential to use `std::scientific. Any double logged without it enabled gives me no information, so I would like to make this a global standard

Comment: What does your logging look like now? Do you have a globally accessible logger? Are you using the BOOST_LOG macros?

Comment: @WilliamKunkel I have a static logger member in each of my classes to set a default for the channel name. To log I use BOOST_LOG_SEV. The thing is that doing `BOOST_LOG_SEV(…) << std::scientific` once is enough to set it for all following messages to all loggers (sources)

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just make a macro `#define CUSTOM_LOGGER(logger, sev) (BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, sev) << std::scientific)` and then use `CUSTOM_LOGGER(...)` in place of `BOOST_LOG_SEV(...)`?

Comment: @WilliamKunkel while it is not an ideal solution, it would certaily help.

Comment: You could also redefine `BOOST_LOG_SEV` to do this behavior. It's not perfect, but it might be better.

Comment: @WilliamKunkel could you point me to a ressource that explains how to do that? I find the `BOOST_LOG_*` macros to be a bit magical and don't really understand what they do exactly.

Comment: Give me a little time; I'll try to get a working implementation and post it in an answer.

Comment: Peeps. Boost Log has a lot of options to achieve this (I did in a few ways), but the question really lacks any detail to decide what is appropriate here. How will the numbers be logged? Are they attributes? Are they just streamed using the streaming operations? What logger instances are used? In other words, OP should show actual code. /cc @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @sehe updated the question with code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@rhashimoto makes a good point about how your current solution will break down with multiple threads/concurrent logging operations. I feel the best solution is to define your own logging macros to replace `BOOST_LOG_SEV` which have the stream modifiers included, like this:

```
#define LOG_SCIENTIFIC(logger, sev) (BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, sev) << std::scientific)
```

Which can just be used as a drop-in replacement for `BOOST_LOG_SEV` which formats numbers as scientific. However, it's probably a pain to go through your code and replace every logging operation with a new custom macro. Instead of defining your own macro, you can also redefine `BOOST_LOG_SEV` to behave how you want. `boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp` defines `BOOST_LOG_SEV` as follows:

```
//! An equivalent to BOOST_LOG_STREAM_SEV(logger, lvl)
#define BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, lvl) BOOST_LOG_STREAM_SEV(logger, lvl)
```

Because `BOOST_LOG_STREAM_SEV` is still a part of the public boost API, you ought to be able to safely redefine `BOOST_LOG_SEV` like this:

```
#define BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, lvl) (BOOST_LOG_STREAM_SEV(logger, lvl) << std::scientific)
```

So long as this is defined after you have included the boost log headers, it should do what you want. However, I would recommend using a macro with a custom name, so that it is clear to others what your code is doing.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that your current method will work in all cases, especially if your code is threaded. It made me nervous when you said that a single logged format flag worked to fix multiple loggers, so I looked at the code (record_ostream.hpp and record_ostream.cpp).

Boost Log uses the [Object pool design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) to provide stream formatters to loggers with the auxiliary struct `stream_provider`. The implementation of `stream_provider` uses thread-local storage (when threading is supported) to use a separate pool of `ostream` instances for each thread. Within a pool, `ostream` instances are created as needed - if only one formatter is needed at a time, only one will ever be created. So I think your current workaround will work for the current Boost Log implementation if you log from a single thread *and* if you never log something in the middle of logging something else.

How this fails with threading should be pretty obvious. Here's a simple example of how this can fail in a single thread:

```c++
static double f(double x) {
   BOOST_LOG(my_logger::get()) << "called f with " << x;
   return x;
}

int main() {
   BOOST_LOG(my_logger::get()) << std::scientific << "format flag";
   BOOST_LOG(my_logger::get()) << "top level " << f(0.01);
   return 0;
}
```

which produces:

```
[2014-04-27 14:16:39.832008] [0x000007fff7a1c631] [info]    format flag
[2014-04-27 14:16:39.832616] [0x000007fff7a1c631] [info]    called f with 0.01
[2014-04-27 14:16:39.832630] [0x000007fff7a1c631] [info]    top level 1.000000e-02
```

Note that the top level log entry (on the third line) is formatted properly while the function log entry (on the second line) is not. This is because the configured stream was in use when the function was called so a separate stream was created and used.

I think @WilliamKunkel's suggestion to define your own logging macro(s) is the best way I've seen to handle this. If you really want to use the Boost macros, however, this hack worked for me on Boost 1.55:

```c++
#include <iomanip>

#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>

typedef boost::log::sources::logger logger_t;
BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT(my_logger, logger_t)

namespace boost {
   namespace log {
      namespace aux {
         template<>
         BOOST_FORCEINLINE record_pump<logger_t> make_record_pump(logger_t& lg, record& rec)
         {
            auto rp = record_pump<logger_t>(lg, rec);
            rp.stream() << std::scientific;
            return rp;
         }
      }
   }
}

int main() {
   BOOST_LOG(my_logger::get()) << "Logging number " << 0.01;
   return 0;
}
```

The basic idea is to specialize the template function that supplies the stream to the macro. When it is specialized to the actual logger class you are using, the specialized implementation passing the `std::scientific` flag will be preferred to the generic implementation.

This is a hack because it depends on implementation details of Boost Log and is not guaranteed to work from release to release. Defining your own macro seems to me like a much better way to go.

I had hoped that something could be done with [`boost::log::basic_formatting_stream`](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/basic_formatting_ostream.html) because its header says:

> Although `basic_formatting_ostream` does not derive from `std::basic_ostream`, users are not required to add
>   special overloads of `operator<<` for it since the stream will by default reuse the operators for `std::basic_ostream`.
>   However, one can define special overloads of `operator<<` for `basic_formatting_ostream` if a certain type needs
>   special formatting when output to log.

Unfortunately, it looks like this only applies to class types and not primitive types as there are member function implementations of `operator<<` for all primitive types.